# Thymeleaf th:text - Put a text without removing HTML structures

Tags: templates, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm new in thymeleaf and I try to create a template. My problem is this code:

```
<h1 th:text="${header.title}" >
   title
   <small th:text="${header.subtitle}" >Subtitle</small>
</h1>
```

I would like to get this output:

```
<h1> TITLE <small> SUBTITLE</small> </h1>
```

But this is the real output:

```
<h1> TITLE </h1>
```

How can I do it, so it does not remove what is inside of "small"?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

I faced the same problem. **The answer is `th:inline='text'`**

This should solve your issue

```
<h1 th:inline="text" >
   [[${header.title}]]
   <small th:text="${header.subtitle}">Subtitle</small>
</h1>
```

---

or you can also use `th:remove="tag"`

```
<h1>
    <span th:text="${header.title}" th:remove="tag">title</span>
    <small th:text="${header.subtitle}" >Subtitle</small>
</h1>
```

Comment: Out of all the other answers, this one was the most useful and to the point. It solved my problem exactly.

Comment: For reference on inlining see: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining

Comment: Why not `th:utext`?

Comment: In my case, static text was getting removed by th:(u)text. This solution fixed it.

Comment: @NickSavenia - `th:utext` would work but is a "dirtier" sollution because it means mixing the text to be displayed with the formatting and this will be harder to mantain. That's why we externalize static text to properties files.

Answer (score 15):

Regardless of the semantics of tags, the correct answer is this one:

```
<h1>
    <span th:text="${header.title}" th:remove="tag">title</span>
    <small th:text="${header.subtitle}" >Subtitle</small>
</h1>
```

In this way Thymeleaf removes the `<span>` tag and the result is what you expect:

```
<h1> 
    TITLE 
    <small>SUBTITLE</small> 
</h1>
```

Answer (score 6):

in addition to @Faraj response, you can also use `th:block` like this

```
<h1>
   <th:block th:utext="${header.title}"/>
   <small th:text="${header.subtitle}" >Subtitle</small>
</h1>
```

Comment: this is great. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying, since the `small` tags in your `h1` will not appear small. The Thymeleaf `th:text` tag will replace all the text in your `h1` tag, that is the reason your output only shows "TITLE". You should place the `<small>` tags outside your `h1` tag.

```
<h1 th:text="${header.title}">title</h1>

<small th:text="${header.subtitle}">Subtitle</small>
```

<strike>And I believe you are looking for this answer:</strike>

```
<h1>
   <span th:text="${header.title}" th:remove="tag">title</span>
   <small th:text="${header.subtitle}">Subtitle</small>
</h1>
```

Comment: the problem is the template I use. If <small> is outside of <h1> will look different.