# How to concatenate th:text and static content with html tags in Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-boot-test

```
<div th:switch="${data.totalPercentage}">
    <td th:case="100" th:text="${data.totalPercentage}"/>
    <td th:case="*" th:text="${data.totalPercentage + '*'}" class="alert alert-warning font-weight-bold"/>
</div>
```

Above expression works but I can not concatenate html tag with th:text. I would like to replace * with fontawesome flag icon `<i class="fas fa-flag"></i>`. Any suggestion?

Comment: See a similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071985/thymeleaf-thtext-put-a-text-without-removing-html-structures?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No real reasons to concatenate here, you should be thinking in terms of HTML.

```
<div th:switch="${data.totalPercentage}">
  <td th:case="100" th:text="${data.totalPercentage}"/>
  <td th:case="*" class="alert alert-warning font-weight-bold">
    <span th:text="${data.totalPercentage}" /> <i class="fas fa-flag"></i>
  </td>
</div>
```