# How to extract the first letter from the string in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

How to extract the first letter from the string in Thymeleaf.

```
<div th:text="${#strings.substring(person.someProperty, 0, 1)}"></div>
```

Can someone please tell the difference between them mentioned below as I can use both insides of the div. Which one should I use. What is the role of square bracket

```
th:text="${ps.name}"

[[${ps.name}]]
```

Comment: Just to add to the notes [already provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66185318/12567365) by @iswailyildiz: The `[[...]]` syntax is called _expression inlining_ and you can read more about how it works [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#inlining). Most of the time you can (and probably should) use `${...}` but _"there are situations in which we could prefer writing expressions directly into our HTML texts"_.

Answer (score 1):

1 - You can try like this to extract the first letter.

```html
<div th:text="${#strings.substring(person.someProperty, 1)}"></div>
```

2 - It is the same in 2 uses. In some cases, you use both for **architectural protection your html structure.** *In some places, I use square brackets to both add extra tags and avoid using `th:remove="tag"`.* Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29317466/2039546