# How to add icon in <h> tag using th:text?

Tags: java, icons, thymeleaf

I want to add MDB icon to the h2 tag - so that it display next to the text. However, I need to use thymeleaf to display one variable, and therefore, everything that is inside my  tag is being replaced.

```
<h2 class="mt-5 text-center text-white" th:text="|${category} - newest posts|">politics - newest posts</h2>
```

If I try to do it that way

```
<h2 class="mt-5 text-center text-white" th:text="|${category} - newest posts|">
politics - newest posts <i class="fas fa-landmark text-warning mx-2"></i>
</h2>
```

nothing is gonna change - because it will be replaced by th:text.
If I try to add this icon outside the h2 tag, it's gonna be under it, so it is not my desired outcome.

My desired outcome in h2: "Politics - newest posts THE_ICON", or "Sport - newest posts THE_ICON".
The problem is just to connect thymeleaf variable with the icon.

Comment: Have a look here: [thymeleaf-thtext-put-a-text-without-removing-html-structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071985/thymeleaf-thtext-put-a-text-without-removing-html-structures)

Comment: I would expect you can use a `<span th:text="${...}">` tag inside your `<h2>` tag, to handle the text, and keep it separate from the `<a>` content (also inside the `<h2>` tag).

Comment: Thanks! It works:)